# Comparing the output of 2 cursors in Oracle PL SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 2 cursors, I would like to compare a field which is returned as the output of one cursor to another field which is also returned as the output of another cursor.

Below is my code:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CHECK_STUDENT AS

        CURSOR SCHOOL_REG IS
          SELECT STUDENT_ID FROM SCHOOL WHERE CLASSROOM IN (1,2,3,4,5);

        CURSOR CLASS_REG IS
          SELECT STUDENT_ID, STUDENT_NAME FROM REGISTER WHERE CLASSROOM = 1;

        FOR X IN CLASS_REG LOOP
          IF X.STUDENT_ID <> SCHOOL_REG.STUDENT_ID THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(X.STUDENT_ID || ' IS NOT REGISTERED IN SCHOOL');
          END IF;
        END LOOP;

    CHECK_STUDENT END;
```

I'm not sure, how can I compare these fields. These cursors have complex queries, I have simplified for the purpose of understanding.

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Is there a requirement to use explicit cursors, and are you doing other things with the results? You might have simplified to a point that it looks like you're using the wrong approach; or that might actually be the case and you don't need these cursors/loops at all (or even PL/SQL).

Comment: Also your code is missing `BEGIN` and the final line is wrong; and you haven't included the error you get when you try to do it this way. Sample data and expected results would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *have* to do it with those two cursors then you would need nested loops, and a boolean flag to keep track:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CHECK_STUDENT AS

  CURSOR SCHOOL_REG IS
    SELECT STUDENT_ID FROM SCHOOL WHERE CLASSROOM IN (1,2,3,4,5);

  CURSOR CLASS_REG IS
    SELECT STUDENT_ID, STUDENT_NAME FROM REGISTER WHERE CLASSROOM = 1;

  FOUND BOOLEAN;
BEGIN

  FOR X IN CLASS_REG LOOP
    FOUND := FALSE;
    FOR Y IN SCHOOL_REG LOOP
      IF Y.STUDENT_ID = X.STUDENT_ID THEN
        FOUND := TRUE;
        EXIT;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(X.STUDENT_ID || ' IS NOT REGISTERED IN SCHOOL');
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

END CHECK_STUDENT;
/
```

But that's pretty inefficient; giving the `school_reg` cursor a parameter to restrict its lookup to a single student would be a slight improvement, but then you might as well use a local query instead of a cursor loop.

It would be much more efficient to do the whole thing in a single SQL statement as @hotfix showed, or as an alternative to those two queries;

```
select student_id || ' IS NOT REGISTERED IN SCHOOL'
from register r
where classroom = 1
and not exists (
  select null
  from school s
  where s.student_id = r.student_id
  and s.classroom in (1,2,3,4,5)
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e8246f01351333fbc5e8ea0a9d0d32dd) showing all of those.

Answer (score 4):

you ca use a  MINUS operator

```
SELECT STUDENT_ID FROM REGISTER WHERE CLASSROOM = 1
minus
SELECT STUDENT_ID FROM SCHOOL WHERE CLASSROOM IN (1,2,3,4,5);
```

or check if student_id not in school like this

```
SELECT STUDENT_ID FROM REGISTER WHERE CLASSROOM = 1
and STUDENT_ID not in (SELECT STUDENT_ID FROM SCHOOL WHERE CLASSROOM IN (1,2,3,4,5)) ;
```